# Access keys in json type column for Eloquent collections?

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel-5

A table column in my database is saved as `json` type. I want to display a keyed value in the saved json object on my blade templates but I'm unsure how.

Let's say I have `$table->json('meta')` in my table schema for `Newsletter` model, with `meta` column having e.g. `{"foo": "bar"}` as value.

How would I retrieve something like `$newsletter->meta->foo`? Since `$newsletter->meta` returns string instead of json object by default on Laravel 5.5 requiring a trivial `json_decode` to convert it.

A cleaner solution besides `json_decode` on every call, would be to use an accessor on that column e.g. `getMetaAttribute` but that's still messy. I want automatic `json` column to PHP object detection, how can I make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a `protected $casts` array inside your model in which you can instruct Eloquent to [automatically convert types](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) of model attributes. In your case that would look like this:

```
/*
 * @property string $meta - json is actually just a string
 */
class Newsletter extends Model {

    protected $casts = [
        'meta' => 'array',
    ];
}

// Now you can use `$meta` as array:
$newsletter = Newsletter::find(1);
$foo = array_get($newsletter->meta, 'foo');
```

But this still does not convert it into an object. Although `object` is mentioned in the docs as being a valid cast type, I can not tell you exactly what it does.

As a note, these `$casts` are not bi-directional. If you want to set `meta` on a `Newsletter` instance, you'd have to create your own facilities to convert any object or array into a json string. Eloquent allows you to define [mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator) on your model to get the job done.

Comment: Thanks, is there any reason why the framework prefers casting `json` columns to string rather than object by default? Is there a way to override this? I'm working with a few dozen models and various columns so I'd want to enable this globally rather than casting each individually.

Comment: Eloquent does not automatically analyze your attributes' values, that would be kind of weird (and very inefficient), if you think about it. JSON data in itself is essentially just a string to php.